# Why was the Tumbleweed badge retired?

Tags: discussion, badges, deprecation

Just out of curiosity, why was this cheeky badge retired? Was it because it was self-deprecating? Did it encourage no-answer questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/), see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/322016#322016) which links to [the blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) explaining the whole thing. Not worth copy-pasting it as an answer; IMO, the target can serve as a duplicate.

Comment: @Jenayah IMO, I think the link to article is answer enough.